# How does "cat x y z > z" work?

Tags: linux, bash

I have three files x,y and z with some contents.

If I run `$cat  x y z  > z` it seems to truncate the file z before writing x and y into z.

I am expecting it to just **concatenate** the contents of x,y and z into z. Can someone explain why this is not so? Also please explain this warning I received

```
$ echo "one" > x
$ echo "two" > y
$ echo "three" > z
$ cat x y z 
  one
  two
  three
$ cat x y z > z
  cat: z: input file is output file
$ cat z
  one
  two
```

Comment: First this will not concatenate the file `z`, it will override content in file `z`. If you want to concatenate you use this `>>`. Also the warning means file `z` is input and its an ouput `z`. You cant do this `z >z`

Comment: what exactly happens when you try? Could you give us an example with three one-word files?  Have you tried to concatenate command `>>`?    What happens

Answer (score 5):

The shell is acting on `>z`, by opening `z` for output and truncating it, before `cat` is even started. `cat` is protecting you from an infinite loop (infinite till your disk is full) by checking the inode of stdout against the inode of each input.

Answer (score -1):

Single `>` overwrites the file on RHS of the operator, whereas `>>` appends the LHS operands to RHS operand. You should try with `>>`. 
This will work with if you are using `cat x y z >> some_other_file`.

Comment: If you use `>>` with the same input and output, you'll get an infinite loop, because it will read from the file, add it to the end, then read it again, then write again, and so on.

Comment: That's why `cat` skips an input file if it's the same as the output.

Comment: `cat y z` >>x ?